# Filepicker.io stat method returning null height & width

Tags: api, filepicker.io, filepicker

I have a bunch of images that I upload to filepicker (that are subsequently stored in my s3 bucket). When I try to query filepicker for the height & width using their stat method in the API it is returning null for both values. Here is the code you can use to check out what I am seeing:

```
var fpfile = { url: 'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/t5efEEtHT8Gjm9dNNxbl' };
filepicker.stat(fpfile, {width: true, height: true},
    function(metadata){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(metadata));
});
```

If you look at the file you'll see that it is a normal jpg. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Or is this a bug in filepicker?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the returned metadata, looks like it thinks it's named "IMG_0281JPG" (note the lack of a period between the name and the JPG) and thus it is not registering as a jpg and the system cannot calculate width and height for non-images.

Setting the filename correctly on upload should help.